# Altering response in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ListAPIView that returns the json response below:

```
[
 {'name': 'Andrew'},
 {'name': 'Daniel'},
]
```

I want to alter it so that the response would look like:

```
{
 "Users": {
    [
     {'name': 'Andrew'},
     {'name': 'Daniel'},
    ]
 }
}
```

How could I do that?

EDIT: Below are is my serializer and the View

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name',)

class UserReadView(ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `list` method inside `UserReadView` and update response body inside it:

```
class UserReadView(ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'Users':{response.data}})
```

Comment: One change, it should be ' return Response({'Users':{response.data}})